# Exibir o nome do serviço no select e o valor no input (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, select, input

Sou entusiasta, faço algumas coisas simples por hobby, e nesse caso travei com uma parte que imagino para vcs deve ser muito simples!
Tenho um sistema de tarefas, no formulário tenho um select de serviços, que exibe o nome do serviço, e preciso que o valor desse serviço seja aplicado em um input.
Pelo servico_id chego no nomeServico no select, no input quero apresentar o valorServico.

```
    //SELECT DE SERVIÇO

    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="servicos_id" class="control-label">Serviço</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="servicos_id" id="servicos_id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                <option value="">Selecionar serviço</option>
                                <?php 
                                foreach($all_servicos as $servico)
                                {
                                    $selected = ($servico['idServicos'] == $this->input->post('servicos_id')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";

                                    echo '<option value="'.$servico['idServicos'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$servico['nomeServico'].'</option>';
                                } 
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('servicos_id');?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

// INPUT VALOR DO SERVIÇO

<div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="valorTarefa" class="control-label">Valor</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" name="valorTarefa" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('valorTarefa'); ?>" class="form-control" id="valorTarefa" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('valorTarefa');?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como as informações estão estruturadas no seu banco de dados, portanto estou presumindo que você está armazenando o valor correspondente de cada serviço na mesma tabela.

Existem várias formas de solucionar esse problema, mas o uso do JavaScript na minha opinião é o ideal para esse tipo de situação.

Segue abaixo uma solução que acredito que resolverá o seu problema.

Entretanto, você terá que trazer o valor de cada serviço juntamente no seu array `$all_servicos` para poder iterar esse dado dentro do seu `<select>`. Agora, caso esse valor esteja armazenado em outra tabela, você terá que realizar uma `JOIN` na sua consulta SQL.

```js
function atribuirValorInput(select) {
  // Pega o valor do atributo data-valor do serviço selecionado...
  var valor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.valor;
  
  // Atribui o valor ao input...
  document.getElementById('valorTarefa').value = valor;
}
```

```html
<!-- Select Serviços -->
<select name="servicos_id" id="servicos_id" onchange="atribuirValorInput(this);">
  <option value="" data-valor="">Selecionar serviço</option>
  <!--
    Trazendo o valor correspondente a cada serviço dentro da variável $servico,
    poderá fazer dessa forma:
    
    <?php
      foreach($all_servicos as $servico)
      {
        echo '<option value="' . $servico['idServicos'] . '" data-valor="' . $servico['valor'] . '">' . $servico['nomeServico'] . '</option>';
      }
    ?>
  -->
  <option value="1" data-valor="10.00">Serviço 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-valor="20.00">Serviço 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-valor="30.00">Serviço 3</option>
</select>

<br><br><br>

<!-- Input Valor -->
<input type="text" name="valorTarefa" value="" id="valorTarefa">
```

Comment: Paulo, muito obrigado! Exatamente o que precisava, funcionando perfeitamente!

Comment: Opa, que bom que deu certo, @LucianoMarangoni!

Comment: Marque a resposta, @LucianoMarangoni